# How can I cancel an API requests in my ngrx effect

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-effects

So on a given page I may dispatch several actions to run a search request all on the same API endpoint. In my effects I have an effect to make this request which looks something like this:

```
    runSearchSuccess$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
            ofType(MyActions.runSearch),
            mergeMap(({searchRequest}) => this.myService.runSearch(searchRequest).pipe(
                map((response) => {
                    return MyActions.runSearchSuccess({ searchResponse: response })
                }),
                catchError(error => {
                    const searchResponse = null;
                    return [
                        MyActions.updateSearchStatuses({searchResponse}),
                    ]
                }),
            )),
        )
    );
```

These requests can take a long time though so if user input on the page changes some requests that are running may become unnecessary and need to be canceled. The data as to what search requests are relevant are in the store so I have a selector to get all of them. What I want to do is watch for changes in this selector and if at any point the search request is no longer relevant I want to cancel it. I dont think I can use TakeUntil because it just depends on what is coming from the selector. I have tried using TakeWhile but cant find a way to actually have it cancel the api call and not just the effect. Is there a way to accomplish this with TakeWhile or is there any better way to manage my active network calls and cancel them when needed?

Comment: instead of `mergeMap` use `switchMap`

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to replace `mergeMap` with `switchMap`.
The difference is that `mergeMap` runs all requests in parallel, while `switchMap` will cancel pending requests when there's a new request.

Docs:

- https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/mergeMap
- https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/switchMap